# What does Bhoota-Nath, one of lord shiva's names, actually mean?

Tags: shiva

Lord shiva is often described as Bhoota-naath. Bhoota, according to my limited knowledge, means both ghostly creatures, and the pancha-bhootas also mean the five elements.
So, does this name refer to lord shiva as the 'Lord of the Ghostly creatures' or the 'Lord of the Elements'?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Thanks, that definitely helped. Also, love the location on your profile, might steal that one :P